# Error trying to run a python function in C++ through pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am trying to export a mesh to VTU format from a C++ program. To do so, I decided to use the `meshio` python library which already implements the required functionality using pybind11.

The code I am running is the following:

```
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};

    std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> pointsConverted;
    pointsConverted.reserve(points.size());
    for (auto p : points) {
        pointsConverted.push_back(std::array{p[0], p[1], p[2]});
    }

    std::vector<std::array<int, 3>> trianglesConverted;
    trianglesConverted.reserve(triangles.size());
    for (auto triangle : triangles) {
        trianglesConverted.push_back(std::array{triangle[0], triangle[1], triangle[2]});
    }

    const auto pyPoints = py::cast(pointsConverted);
    const auto pyTriangles = py::cast(trianglesConverted);

    py::module::import("sys").attr("path").attr("append")("blablabla");
    const auto pyWrapper = py::module::import("VTKExporter");
    pyWrapper.attr("writeVTU")(pyPoints, pyTriangles);
```

As you can see, I convert my data to stl types and I send this data to a function in python

```
import meshio


def writeVTU(points, triangles):
    print(points)
    print(triangles)
    meshio.Mesh(points, {"triangle": triangles}).write("test.vtu")
```

However, this fails with the following error

```
[[-0.0, -0.0, -0.0], [-0.0, -0.0, 0.0], [-0.0, 0.0, -0.0], [-0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, -0.0, -0.0], [0.0, -0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, -0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]                                                                               [48/2685]
[[4, 2, 0], [2, 7, 3], [6, 5, 7], [1, 7, 5], [0, 3, 1], [4, 1, 5], [4, 6, 2], [2, 6, 7], [6, 4, 5], [1, 3, 7], [0, 2, 3], [4, 0, 1]]                                                                                                                                  
CAPTURED EXCEPTION 'SystemError: Objects/structseq.c:481: bad argument to internal function                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
At:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py(6): <module>                                                                                                                                                                    
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                                                                             
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(883): exec_module                                                                                                                                                                                  
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(703): _load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                                        
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1006): _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                              
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1027): _find_and_load                                                                                                                                                                                       
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                                                                             
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1079): _handle_fromlist                                                                                                                                                                                     
  /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py(10): <module>                                                                                                                                                                  
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                                                                             
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(883): exec_module                                                                                                                                                                                  
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(703): _load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                                        
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1006): _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                              
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1027): _find_and_load                                                                                                                                                                                       
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                                                                             
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1079): _handle_fromlist                                                                                                                                                                                     
  /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py(51): <module>                                                                                                                                                                    
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                                                                             
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(883): exec_module                                                                                                                                                                                  
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(703): _load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                                        
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1006): _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                              
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1027): _find_and_load                                                                                                                                                                                       
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                                                                             
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1079): _handle_fromlist                                                                                                                                                                                     
  /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py(144): <module>                                                                                                                                                                        
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                                                                             
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(883): exec_module                                                                                                                                                                                  
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(703): _load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                                        
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1006): _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                              
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1027): _find_and_load                                                                                                                                                                                       
  /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/meshio/ansys/_ansys.py(8): <module>                                                                                                                                                                     
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                                                                             
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(883): exec_module                                                                                                                                                                                  
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(703): _load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                                        
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1006): _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                              
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1027): _find_and_load                                                                                                                                                                                       
  /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/meshio/ansys/__init__.py(1): <module>                                                                                                                                                                   
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                                                                             
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>(883): exec_module                                                                                                                                                                                  
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(703): _load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                                        
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1006): _find_and_load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                              
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1027): _find_and_load                                                                                                                                                                                       
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                                                                             
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(1079): _handle_fromlist
  /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/meshio/_cli/_ascii.py(4): <module>
  <frozen importlib._bootstrap>(241): _call_with_frames_removed
...
```

I have also tried to run this code directly from C++ import `meshio` module with `py::module::import("meshio")` with the same error.

I dont understand this error or how to solve it. Any ideas will be welcome.

Comment: In `writeVTU`, are you able to convert `points` and `triangles` to numpy arrays without getting this error?

Comment: Yes, I can do the conversion to a np array. I get the same error though